# Return double index of collection's element while iterating

Tags: iterator, iteration, kotlin

In Kotlin documentation I found the following example:

```
for ((index, value) in array.withIndex()) {
    println("the element at $index is $value")
}
```

Is it possible (and how) to do the similar with 2D matrix:

```
for ((i, j, value) in matrix2D.withIndex()) {
    // but iterate iver double index: i - row, j - column
    if (otherMatrix2D[i, j] > value) doSomething()
}
```

How to make support this functionality in Kotlin class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While the solutions proposed by [miensol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/155213/miensol) and [hotkey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2196460/hotkey) are correct it would be the least efficient way to iterate a matrix. For instance, the solution of [hotkey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2196460/hotkey) makes `M * N` allocations of `Cell<T>` plus `M` allocations of `List<Cell<T>>` and `IntRange` plus one allocation of `List<List<Cell<T>>>` and `IntRange`. Moreover lists resize when new cells are added so even more allocations happen. That's too much allocations for just iterating a matrix.

### Iteration using an inline function

I would recommend you to implement a very similar and very effective at the same time extension function that will be similar to `Array<T>.forEachIndexed`. This solution doesn't do any allocations at all and as efficient as writing nested `for` cycles.

```
inline fun <T> Matrix<T>.forEachIndexed(callback: (Int, Int, T) -> Unit) {
  for (i in 0..cols - 1) {
    for (j in 0..rows - 1) {
      callback(i, j, this[i, j])
    }
  }
}
```

You can call this function in the following way:

```
matrix.forEachIndexed { i, j, value ->
  if (otherMatrix[i, j] > value) doSomething()
}
```

### Iteration using a destructive declaration

If you want to use a traditional `for`-loop with destructive declaration for some reason there exist a way more efficient but hacky solution. It uses a sequence instead of allocating multiple lists and creates only a single instance of `Cell`, but the `Cell` itself is mutable.

```
data class Cell<T>(var i: Int, var j: Int, var value: T)

fun <T> Matrix<T>.withIndex(): Sequence<Cell<T>> {
  val cell = Cell(0, 0, this[0, 0])
  return generateSequence(cell) { cell ->
    cell.j += 1
    if (cell.j >= rows) {
      cell.j = 0
      cell.i += 1
      if (cell.i >= cols) {
        return@generateSequence null
      }
    }
    cell.value = this[cell.i, cell.j]
    cell
  }
}
```

And you can use this function to iterate a matrix in a `for`-loop:

```
for ((i, j, item) in matrix.withIndex()) {
   if (otherMatrix[i, j] > value) doSomething()
}
```

This solution is lightly less efficient than the first one and not so robust because of a mutable `Cell`, so I would really recommend you to use the first one.

Comment: Is there a way to make similar functionality as destructuring in for loop, but without allocating every time Cell object and then destructuring them? I mean rewrite code with components calls?

Comment: There's no way I'm aware of to make it with the same efficiency but I have an idea how it can be implemented much more efficient than in other answers. I need some time to try and code it so I'll add the second solution tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks! That's a great answer! I agree, the first solution is better, even despite it's not as usual as traditional `for`-loop

Comment: Good point about performance! I've run some tests and updated my answer, pointing your solution as more performant. The difference is 2x to 3x, which is actually crucial for performance critical code.

Answer (score 5):

These two language features are used for implementing the behaviour that you want:

- For-loops can be used with any class that has a method [that provides an iterator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#for-loops).

  ```
  for (item in myItems) { ... }
  ```

  This code will compile if `myItems` has function `iterator()` returning something with functions `hasNext(): Boolean` and `next()`.

  Usually it is an [`Iterable<SomeType>`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-iterable/) implementation (some collection), but you can add `iterator()` method to an existing class as an [extension](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#extension-functions), and you will be able to use that class in for-loops as well.
- For [destructuring declaration](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html), the item type should have `componentN()` functions.

  ```
  val (x, y, z) = item
  ```

  Here the compiler expects `item` to have `component1()`, `component2()` and `component3()` functions. You can also use [`data` classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html#data-classes), they have these functions generated.

  Destructuring in for-loop works in a similar way: the type that the iterator's `next()` returns must have `componentN()` functions.

---

Example implementation (not pretending to be best at performance, see below):

- Class with destructuring support:

  ```
  class Cell<T>(val i: Int, val j: Int, val item: T) {
      operator fun component1() = i
      operator fun component2() = j
      operator fun component3() = item
  }
  ```

  Or using `data` class:

  ```
  data class Cell<T>(val i: Int, val j: Int, val item: T)
  ```
- Function that returns `List<Cell<T>>` (written as an extension, but can also be a member function):

  ```
  fun <T> Matrix<T>.withIndex() =
      (0 .. height - 1).flatMap { i -> 
          (0 .. width - 1). map { j ->
              Cell(i, j, this[i, j])
          }
      }
  ```
- The usage:

  ```
  for ((i, j, item) in matrix2d.withIndex()) { ... }
  ```

---

**UPD** Solution offered by [Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/170842/michael) actually performs better (run [this test](https://gist.github.com/h0tk3y/b8fe0da736f69e4c0685b525bbaf3577), the difference is about 2x to 3x), so it's more suitable for performance critical code.

Comment: In addition to native Kotlin solutions, any Java solution, such as Guava's [Table.cellSet()](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Table.html#cellSet()), can be used.

Answer (score 3):

The following method:

```
data class Matrix2DValue<T>(val x: Int, val y: Int, val value: T)
fun withIndex(): Iterable<Matrix2DValue<T>> {
   //build the list of values
}
```

Would allow you to write `for` as:

```
    for ((x, y, value) in matrix2d.withIndex()) {
        println("value: $value, x: $x, y: $y")
    }
```

Bear in mind though that the order in which you declare `data class` properties defines the values of `(x, y, value)` - as opposed to `for` variable names. You can find more [information about destructuring in the Kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html).